# Conditional Join with DPLYR

Tags: r, join, conditional-statements, dplyr

I am attempting to join two data frames by a variable that has a different name and by a single conditional criterion (i.e. the year) in the source.

Investigating various solutions has not provided me with an answer.

**Data**:

```
x_6.0_2011 <- data.frame(t = c("1", "2", "3", "7"), value_1 = c("0.9", "0.6", "0.1", "0.8"))

x <- data.frame(year = c("2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"), t.nr = c("1", "1", "2", "7"), value = c("0.2", "0.5", "0.7", "0.3"))
```

**What I tried:**

```
x2011 <-   ifelse(x$year == '2011', 
                  left_join(x, x_6.0_2011, by = c('t.nr' = 't')), 0)
```

--> producing a list - so wrong solution path

```
x20111 <- left_join(x, x_6.0_2011, by = c('t.nr' = 't'), ,year== 2011 )
```

--> producing a df but only replacing the correct value and coyping in the remainders from the x_6.0_2011 - so wrong solution path

```
xx_6.02011 <- left_join(filter(x, year == '2011'), x_6.0_2011, by = c('t.nr' = 't'))
```

--> producing df with one line but I would like to have kept the other entries not containing any value

**Result Expected:**

```
Yr       t.nr   value  value_1
2010     1       0.2    0
2011     1       0.3    0.9
2012     2       0.7    0
2013     7       0.3    0
```

... or similar at least in the last column not a value I cannot deduces.

The minimal example works however my working project (217 variable) still produces an error:

I do consistently get: 
*Error: data_frames can only contain 1d atomic vectors and lists*

Any advice is more than appreciated. Or are my attempts to simplistic?

Comment: I tried your third solution and it gives me one row as is expected.  I am not getting any error.  But there is a warning as the columns in both are `factor` class.  So, `In left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
  joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector` which is a friendly one.

Comment: May be you need to do another `left_join` if `df1` is `x_6.02011` and `df2` as `x`. `left_join(df2, left_join(filter(df2, year=='2011'), df1, by =c('t.nr'='t')))`  If you are using the devel version of data.table, the same output can be got with `setDT(df1)[df2, on=c('t'='t.nr')][year!=2011, value_1:=NA_character_][]`

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply! Yes, I do get the warning, too. Stems from fumbling the example together to quickly. Sorry! I thought about setDT but the result does not meet my expectancies. Allow another moment to post another df.

Comment: It may be better to show the expected output as I am guessing what might be your expected.

Comment: I think your expected output has some values at different positions.  `2011 1 0.3 0.9` would be `2011 1 0.5 0.9` as per the initial data.  In that case the `setDT` result I get is correct one ie. `setDT(df1)[df2, on=c('t'='t.nr')][year!=2011, value_1:='0'][]`

Comment: I close the post as solved - my issues lies within the original dataframe - the join works as designed. THANKS for setDT - that solves my query.

Comment: SURE!!!!! Apologies....!!! I still think something reacts oddly with dplyr... style: https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/999 but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `devel` version of `data.table`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
setDT(df1)[df2, on=c('t'='t.nr')][year!=2011, value_1:='0'][]
#    t value_1 year value
#1: 1       0 2010   0.2
#2: 1     0.9 2011   0.5
#3: 2       0 2012   0.7
#4: 7       0 2013   0.3
```

Comment: THX AGAIN for your endeavours!